# i use Intent to put extra and get extra on activity but next time data of get extra is data of first put extra (sorry my english is bad)

Tags: c#, android-intent, xamarin.forms, xamarin.android

ex: first time: i put 18001090 and i receive : 18001090

second time: i put 056113  but i receive : 18001090

I put extra

```
 Intent notificationIntent = new Intent(context, typeof(MainActivity));
                notificationIntent.SetAction("android.intent.action.MAIN");
                notificationIntent.PutExtra("number", incomingNumber);
```

On MainActivity

```
var number = this.Intent.GetStringExtra("number");
```

Comment: Are you telling me when you did this, it gave you the same result that it gave you the first time

Comment: @G.hakim i use BroadcastReceiver with action PHONE_STATE , My app will show notification if have outgoing call, when click notification, i will put extra outgoing number and start Main activity but Main activity only get extra is data of first time put extra

Answer (score 0):

I use Intent to put extra and get extra, but I don't get the result as you, here is my code.

I add EditText and Button on layout5 and TextView on layout6.

Mainactivity:

```
 private EditText edittext;
    protected override void OnCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {        

        base.OnCreate(savedInstanceState);
        SetContentView(Resource.Layout.layout5);

        btn1 = FindViewById<Button>(Resource.Id.button1);

        edittext = FindViewById<EditText>(Resource.Id.edittext1);
        btn1.Click += Btn1_Click1;



    }

    private void Btn1_Click1(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {


        Intent i = new Intent(this, typeof(Activity1));
        //Add PutExtra method data to intent.   
        i.PutExtra("Name", edittext.Text.ToString());
        //StartActivity   
        StartActivity(i);

    }
```

Avtivity1:

```
private TextView text;
    protected override void OnCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        base.OnCreate(savedInstanceState);
        SetContentView(Resource.Layout.layout6);

        // Create your application here
        string name = Intent.GetStringExtra("Name");
        text = FindViewById<TextView>(Resource.Id.textview1);
        text.Text = name;
        Log.Debug("123" ,name);
    }
```